# "Sample problem" translation

Tags: traduction, anglais

> Let's see how the model could be applied to a sample problem.

Comment peut-on interpreter la tournure sample problem ? Je pense à :

> 1) Voyons comment le modèle pourrait être appliqué à un exemple de
>   problème.
>
> 2) Voyons comment le modèle pourrait être appliqué à un problème type.
>
> 3) Voyons comment le modèle pourrait être appliqué à un problème
>   typique.
>
> 4) Voyons comment le modèle pourrait être appliqué à un
>   problème-example.
>
> 5) Une autre...

Comment: EEEk... Please tell use more! BTW, if the *model* is in the field of *model order reduction* then... it could actually make sense to translate *sample problem* by *problème d'**échantillonnage***

Comment: Merci @aCOSwt : Tu as raison. Il fallait que je donne des détails. C'est dans le domaine de la mécanique. J'ai quelques diapositives préparées pour les étudiants. La sommaire va comme ça : 1) Introduction, 2) Quantité de mouvement et moment cinétique, 3)..., 4) **Sample problem** (comme application de ce que les étudiants ont déjà vu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je penche pour la deuxième tournure :

> Voyons comment le modèle pourrait être appliqué à un problème type.

Comment: C'est bon, merci !

Comment: ou  *...pourrait **s'appliquer** à...*.